# Jenkins: How to enter credentials for SSH login

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, credentials

Trying to get started with Jenkins, I fail in the beginning with retrieving the code from my own GIT-service. I have no clue how to enter the credentials for the SSH login. I'm on Jenkins 2.204.1.
My preferred approach would be to retrieve the private key dynamically from my PuTTy Pageant (the SSH Agent plugin is installed). But would also be fine with retrieving it from my encrypted keyfile.

But I do not see, how I can enter this information. The panels offer me to enter the GIT-Repository, the private key and a passphrase. I can choose whether I will enter the private key directly (what does this mean - there is no way to enter it indirectly).
Because of the passphrase I think the private key to enter is the encrypted one (copy&paste from the encrypted keyfile) and is probably decrypted by the passphrase.
But I also tried with the decrypted private key (without passphrase). Neither works.

I looked up a lot of articles dealing with my problem, but nothing really helped me. The current users handbook is empty on the pages decribing the credentials. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Credentials Plugin for Jenkins

Please refer to this article - [Configuring SSH authentication between GitHub and Jenkins](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/02/27/configuring-ssh-authentication-between-github-and-jenkins/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, but no, doesn't help. "SSH Credentials" is by default installed and your description in a way describes the way I did. (Have created the key with PuTTYgen).

Comment: Just the panel for entering the credentials is different: I have only the choice to enter the private key, but your description allows to select a random key file or from Jenkins home.

Comment: My answer has been inserted directly behind my question - though from the sequence it should have been placed here.

Answer (score 0):

It works. But is strange anyway.

I had some failures here - after some tries I just waited in "Source Code Management" for testing the "git.exe"-command. This always fails with:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h -- GITCommonBasics@udsdiskstation:~/CommonBasics.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
```

But when running the job all is fine. I would have saved lot of time when I had not relied on this message.